# in which file and where should i put a modal bootstrap?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I need to add a modal popup to the following web app:

https://github.com/gunet/openeclass/tree/3.12.x

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="wizardmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Property</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <!-- Smart Wizard HTML -->
          <div id="smartwizard">
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#step-1">Step 1<br /><small>Add Property</small></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#step-2">Step 2<br /><small>Type of Property</small></a></li>
              </ul>

              <div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>


I'm using modal show.

 $(window).on('load',function(){
    $('#wizardmodal').modal('show');
    });
```

In which file and which line should i add the above?

I have tried adding the above in index.php but nothing shows up

Comment: I found [demo.openeclass.org](https://demo.openeclass.org) and saw there that it's using bootstrap version 3.2 from 2014. So your code seems correct. But to decide where to put this code would require a deeper understanding of the structure of this platform, and I think that is beyond the scope of a simple Stack Overflow question. It is probably better to pose this question to the makers, which you can find on github. If you ask this question there, don't forget to mention the purpose of the modal and when you want it to appear.

Comment: the authors support only University installations, not standalone ones. Also they do not respond to my question regarding altering the code. I want it to appear once per user in the front page. I have tried to put it in index.php and in https://github.com/gunet/openeclass/blob/3.12.x/template/default/js/main.js but nothing shows up

Answer (score 0):

I can see from your code you're running bootstrap version 4. Here's a link to the documentation for how to use a modal https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal.

I added a little modification to your code to get it to run. Check it below.

```js
$(window).on('load',function(){
  $('#wizardmodal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="wizardmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Property</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;<span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- Smart Wizard HTML -->
          <div id="smartwizard">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#step-1">Step 1<br /><small>Add Property</small></a></li>
              <li><a href="#step-2">Step 2<br /><small>Type of Property</small></a></li>
            </ul>
          <div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: the problem is i do not know where to puth the snippet, in which file. I tried with the above also, in index.php, but nothing shows up

Comment: Can you post your full index.php file?

Comment: https://github.com/gunet/openeclass/blob/3.11.x/index.php in this file, i do not know where to put the code

Comment: You're using a cms for your application which I don't know much about. Usually, with bootstrap, you can put your modal code before the closing body tag and the other jquery piece of code in the script tag on the top of your file.